# Redirect request from specific domain

Tags: redirect, dns

Hey guys,
Ex: - root domain - domain.com
A link on **example.net** leads to **domain.com**

Could that request be redirected to **domain.com/redirect/** and allow requests from other domain names to access **domain.com** with no redirection?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: So you want to redirect to `domain.com/redirect` *only* if the referrer is `example.com`?

Comment: Yes, thank you for shortening it :)

Comment: @abhishek-ravi - Unfortunately no, but I'm still hoping.
It could be a great tool if Apache can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an apache server with a suitable setup to test it right now, but mod_rewrite should be able to do it with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/redirect [R=301]
```